# How to check if a python class has particular method or not?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

```
class C(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        print "in C init"
        super(C, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        print "\tin C setup"

    def runtest(self):
        print "\t\tin C runtest"

    def teardown(self):
        print "\t\t\tin C teardown"
```

I have such classes in different modules. For eg class `A`,`B`,`C` etc.. In one module I'm considering only classes who have setup and teardown methods. Suppose Class `A` doesn't have setup method, I don't want to consider it for further parth of my program where I'm building list of classes having setup and runtest module. Is there any python function I can use for the same? What is the correct way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I would argue this is a case for an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/abc.html).

```
class Test(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def setup(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def teardown(self):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Test:
            if (any("setup" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__) and 
               any("teardown" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro___)):
                return True
        return NotImplemented
```

This defines the type `Test`, and a `__subclasshook__` function that checks if a class defines `setup()` and `teardown()`. This means any such class will be treated as a subclass of `Test` - that is `issubclass()` will return `True` for `issubclass(C, Test)`.

Of course, you could just do the check manually using the same methodology as the `__subclasshook__` function, but abstract base classes provide a nice (and standard) way to define the contract you want fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  if (any("setup" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__) and 
               any("teardown" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro___)): worked well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `hasattr` and `callable` on the classes themselves (classes are objects afterall), i.e. something like

```
if hasattr( C, 'setup' ) and callable( C.setup ):
      classes_with_setup.append(C)
```

or, in terms of a list comprehension

```
classes_with_setup=[ U for U in [A,B,C...] if hasattr(U,'setup') and callable(U.setup)]
```

to setup your list of classes with those features.

This methodology does detect inheritance:

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def f(self):
   ...:         print 'hi'
   ...:         

In [2]: class B(A):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: hasattr(A,'f')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: hasattr(B,'f')
Out[4]: True

In [5]: hasattr(B,'f') and callable(B.f)
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: This won't work in situations where the method is provided by a superclass.

Comment: @Lattyware I just ran a test case, and this logic does detected inherited members.

Comment: Indeed, so it appears. I'm mistaken, but I assume there must be a good reason for the [doc examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/abc.html) and [stdlib implementations](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/_collections_abc.py) to use this method. I thought that was why, but clearly not.

Comment: @Lattyware I'm running 2.7 -- maybe it has changed for 3.0?

Comment: Ah, so [the reasoning](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-August/103200.html) appears to be that `hasattr()` actually accesses the value, which could potentially cause side effects (very unlikely in this kind of case, you'd have to have the function being provided by some descriptor with side effects, but not impossible). This means that where you want to ensure no side effects are fired, checking the `__dict__` and down the `__mro__` is the safer option.

Comment: It does work in 3.x, but as it does have potential side-effects (however unlikely), it is not the optimal method of checking this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getattr` and `callable` methods

```
setup_method = getattr(your_object, "setup_method", None)
if callable(setup_method):
    setup_method(self.path.parent_op)
```

First check if the object has an attribute called "`setup_method`" then check it that attribute is a method and then call it.

Comment: The question asks for a way to tell if a *class* has the required method - this checks if an *instance* has the required method. These are not the same as the class will not have inherited methods as directly accessible attributes.

Comment: As pointed out by Dave on [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25296279/722121), I was actually wrong, this method could be adapted and work with inherited methods, however it does have the potential to cause side effects, as such, it's not an optimal solution, even when adapted to fit the question's case.