# Determinate if class has user defined __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to identify if a class that i received via an argument has a user defined `__init__` function in the class that was passed. Not in any super class.

```
class HasInit(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class NoInit(object):
  pass

class Base(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class StillNoInit(Base):
  pass

def has_user_defined_init_in(clazz):
  return True if # the magic

assert has_user_defined_init_in(HasInit) == True
assert has_user_defined_init_in(NoInit) == False
assert has_user_defined_init_in(StillNoInit) == False
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295327/how-to-check-if-a-python-class-has-particular-method-or-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
def has_user_defined_init_in(clazz):
    return "__init__" in clazz.__dict__
```

Comment: Just got few seconds shy of posting this :-).